# HTML, CSS: How to override settings from *{}(!important is not working)

Tags: html, css, colors

In my code I set the text to be red, but it is not working. Can anybody help me with this? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uk1u62vf/2/

```
Thank you!
```

Comment: **p{ color:red !important;  }** also will work

Comment: That is not exactly what I want and I already have an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not change titles to indicate the question is solved. - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add p into

`.list-item > .card  {
  color:red !important;
  }`

Should look like this

`.list-item > .card  p{
  color:red;
  }`

you could also replace it with

`.content  p{
  color:red;
  }`

**EDIT:** Explanation

You didn't target paragraph element. You have targeted div element with class `card` which is parent of div with class `content` which is again parent of paragraph you are trying to target.

Comment: Works also without "!important", which should always be preferred

Comment: Thanks, I hate to use the !important and this is the perfect solution.

Comment: If you are setting the color directly on `p`, then why do you still need `!important`?

Comment: I didn't say that you need it. You may set it or you may not.